# PHP recursive function return value

Tags: php, recursion, return, php-gd

I have written a recursive function in PHP to crop text. The cropped text will have ... attached to the end. Non-cropped text will be returned in its original state.

It works if the text fits the maximum width. However, if it does not fit in the given width, the function will not return a value, but it should. It seems that the whole *return* statement is ignored. If I replace the *return* with *echo*, it shows the correct value.

The expected result: 
-TEST ZIN 
-TEST ZI 
-TEST Z 
-TEST 
-TES 
-TE... (nothing is returned here, so this will never be shown)

```
function check_length($str, $max, $size = SIZE, $rec = false) {
    echo "FUNCTION $str ";
    list($left, , $right) = imageftbbox($size, 0, FONTURL, $str);
    if($rec == false) {
        if(($right - $left) > $max) {
            echo 'if 1<br />';
            check_length(substr($str, 0, -1), $max, $size, true);
        } else {
            echo 'else 1<br />';
            return $str;
        }
    } else {
        if(($right - $left) > ($max - 9)) {
            echo 'if 2<br />';
            check_length(substr($str, 0, -1), $max, $size, true);
        } else {
            echo 'else 2<br />';
            return "$str...";
        }
    }
}

echo check_length('TEST ZIN', 30);
```

*Note*: the echo's in the function are for debugging.

Comment: You should put what the constant 'SIZE' is equal to.  It'll make running this a bit easier, so we're in the same ballpark.

Comment: A function to crop text? Could you explain a bit more what your trying to accomplish with this function?

Comment: You are right. Sorry about that. SIZE = 9 and FONTURL = '/usr/share/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSans.ttf'

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You're not returning the text properly, e.g.,

```
    } else {
        echo 'else 1<br />';
        return $str;  // <--- nothing in the 'parent' caller catches this, so it's lost
    }
```

Anywhere you do recursion and need to return a value, you must capture/return the recursive call itself:

```
    return check_length(substr($str, 0, -1), $max, $size, true);
```

or

```
    $newstr = check_length(...);
    return $newstr;
```

Comment: Thank you. This works fine. I have never done 'real world' recursive function, so this is all new for me. The first solution you suggested works like a charm.

Answer (score 3):

Return the result of your recursive function call ;)

```
return check_length(substr($str, 0, -1), $max, $size, true);
```